# Tough looking existence

Tags: functions

If $a,b>0,a<b$ show that there exist $c,d\in (a,b)$ such that: $$ \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{c+d} = a^{c} \cdot b^{d} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking logarithms in the equality we get
$$
d=\frac{\log a-\log\frac{a+b}{2}}{\log\frac{a+b}{2}-\log b}c
$$
As $b>a>0$ this defines a line trough the origin in the plane $(c,d)$ and to solve the equation we need the line hits the open rectangle $(a,b)\times(a,b)$. Consequently the slope
of that line must be between $a/b$ and $b/a$ (given by the lower right corner and the upper left corner of the rectangle). To express this better we write $t=b/a>1$ and then
$$
d=f(t)c,\quad f(t)=\frac{\log\frac{2}{1+t}}{\log\frac{1+t}{2t}}.
$$
The condition on the slope is now $\ \frac{1}{t}<f(t)<t\ $ for $\ t>1$, or in other form:
$$
\begin{cases}
g_1(t)=tf(t)-1>0,\\g_2(t)=t-f(t)>0,
\end{cases}
$$
for $t>0$. This is true! Although I have only graphed the functions $g_i$, both vanish at $t=1$ and are strictly encreasing for $t>0$. 
Hence the initial equation has always a solution.

A remark: the inequalities $\ \frac{1}{t}<f(t)<t\ $ also mean that the difference suggested in the previous answer is positive at $(c,d)=(a,b)$ and negative at $(c,d)=(b,a)$ and there is a solution in any path in the open rectangle connecting the two vertices.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: write $f(c, d) = \left (\frac{a+b}{2} \right)^{c+d} - a^c b^d$. Can you show that $f $ is negative at some point, positive at some other point, and then apply continuity of the function to show that it attains the value 0 somewhere?

Comment: The equation can be solved using logarithms, to get $d=\lambda c$ for some coefficient $\lambda>0$. This gives a line in a plane through the origin that must hit the square $(a,b)\times(a,b)$. This is the case por instance if $a$ and be are close. In general one has to discuss the limit of $a/b$...

Answer (score 1):

We may write $a$ and $b$ in the form
$$a=e^{u-v},\quad b=e^{u+v},\qquad v>0\ .$$
Then ${a+b\over2}=\cosh v$. Taking logarithms in the given equation we therefore have to achieve
$$(c+d)(u+\log\cosh v)=c(u-v)+d(u+v)\ ,$$
which is equivalent with
$$(c+d)\log\cosh v=(d-c) v\ .\tag{1}$$
Since we have one equation and two unknowns we invoke symmetry and try
$$c=e^{u-\delta},\quad d=e^{u+\delta},\qquad\delta>0\ .$$
Entering this into $(1)$ we obtain
$$\cosh\delta\>\log\cosh v=\sinh\delta \> v\ ,$$
or
$${1\over v}\log\cosh v=\tanh\delta\ .\tag{2}$$
If we can solve $(2)$ for $\delta$ with a $\delta<v$ we are done, for then $c$ and $d$ will automatically lie in the interval $\ ]a,b[\ $. Now
$$0<{1\over v}\log\cosh v={1\over v}\int_0^v \tanh s\>ds=\int_0^1\tanh(t\>v)\>dt<\tanh v\ .$$
This shows that the solution $\delta$ of $(2)$ is indeed $<v$.

Comment: Nice! Let me add this. You in fact bet for a solution $ab=cd$, which is a hyperbola trough the vertices of $(a,b)\times(a,b)$ and you use hyperbolic functions. Also, the conditions $a<d<b$ ($d=f(t)c$, $t=b/a$ in my solution) give $a^2<d^2=f(t)cd=f(t)ab<b^2$, hence $1/t<f(t)<t$ again.